# DE : $\frac{\mathrm d^2(F)}{\mathrm dx^2} -S^2 \cdot (F) = K \cdot e^{-ax}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE that I need to solve and I am not sure where to begin:

$$\frac{d^2(F)}{dx^2} -S^2 \cdot (F) = K \cdot e^{-ax}$$

Does anyone know any techniques that I could use?

Comment: The general method is 1) find the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation, 2) find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation, 3) put the two together.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand the homogenous solution part - Sorry I should have specified, I need help with the particular form

Comment: Try $F(x)=Ae^{-ax}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not sure what you are talking. Are you referring to using undetermined coefficients? There is also the constant K. Also, there is an S^2. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Is $S$ a constant or a function of $x$?

Comment: @Amzoti It is a constant

Comment: You know, I have sometimes written very complicated, confusing comments on questions, but I don't think I have ever written a simpler comment than "Try $F(x)=Ae^{-ax}$." It means exactly what it says. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry Gerry, I tried your method. I got K/(a^2-S^2)*exp(-ax). I Am not sure if I did this correctly

Comment: The good thing about solving a differential equation is that you can always check your answer by differentiating (twice, in this case) and substituting back in to see whether it satisfies the equation.

Comment: The general solution of your ODE is K Exp[-a x] / (a^2 - S^2) + C1 Exp[S x] + C2 Exp[-S x]

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Shoudlnt there be an x for particular solution since if a = s then particular has same for as homegenous?

Comment: @JacksonHart. If a=S, the solution seems to be - K (1 + 2 S x) Exp[-S x] / (4 S^2) + C1 Exp[S x] + C2 Exp[- S x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- For the homogeneous, we have:

$$m^2 - s^2 = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \pm ~ s$$

This gives:

$$F_h(x) = c_1e^{-sx} + c_2 e^{sx}$$

- For the particular, using Undetermined Coefficients, we can choose:

$$F_p = w e^{-a x}$$

Substitute into the ODE and solve for $w$.

Comment: Could you confirm that my particular solution: K/(a^2-S^2)*exp(-ax) is correct using your method?

Comment: Correct. Please note the restriction on $a^2 = s^2$. Recall to upvote and/or accept answers that are helpful. On the restriction, we get a different answer For example, $choose a = s = 3$ and see what happens. Regards

Comment: Can I ask you more question? If the particular solution has the form e^(-ax), will that interfere with the homogeneous part that has e^(-sx)?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely my comment. In this special case, we would choose $y_p = w x e^{-ax}$. See the denominator of the solution you found, it tells you that there is an issue here and that should be accounted for. Regards

Comment: So you need to add this extra x even if one is raised to the sx and the other to the ax?

Comment: Recall, since there is no restriction (at least you did not make the statement) that says $a$ cannot equal $s$. If it does, that is the problem case which has that slightly different form. The reason for this is the the homogeneous solution already has that exponential and when you sub it back in, the DEQ is zero. You need a particular solution that is not zero. Clear?

Comment: I do not see how adding an x out in front gets rid of the possibility of  a equaling s

Comment: No, we found a general solution as I describe, but there is a single restriction for the special case when $a=x$.

Comment: I think I was referring to a = s because denomiator is zero. You did so because it would have same form

Comment: Can I just have my general form include the x for the particular?

Comment: Those two statements equate to the same thing in the end.

Comment: So having Total solution: = C1e^-sx + C2e^sx + wxe^-ax

Comment: Yes, but only for the special case. What I show is for everything else. It is like saying $f(x) = 1/x$. It is okay everywhere except $x = 0$. In fact, it is easier to write it as a piecewise solution, just like a piecewise function.

Comment: Right but I need to apply BC's now and I do not think I am suppose to have two different results

Comment: Since it is like a PW function, you can use the same condition for both.

Comment: a PW function? I understand I can use the same BC's for both so you are suggesting I have to solutions? One for special case and one general case?

Comment: Precisely! Why is this confusing you so much?

Comment: The reason I am skeptical is becuase after I apply BC's and get total solution, when I plug back in, I do not get right hand side

Comment: For the general or special case?

Comment: I only tried general so far

Comment: Add the BC's to question and I will look at. Please post complete questions to avoid this.

Comment: Nevermind, it works! Thanks! You were a great help!

Comment: You are welcome. Regards.

Comment: Sorry just one more question. I do not see how having a special case is necessary. If a does equal s then we have a 0 in the denominator regardless the solution would not exist. Why is it necessary then?

Comment: $f'' - a^2 f = k e^{-ax}$ (for the special case, where $s=a$)

Comment: it should not be -a^2 but -s^2

Comment: Yes, but $S$ is a constant, and that constant can equal $a$.

Comment: So here the particular needs to have -Kae(-ax) since otherwise it is similar to homogenous solution?

Comment: In this special case $y_p = b ~ x ~e^{-ax}$, since the homogeneous already has an $e^{-ax}$ term in it.

Comment: I really do not think that works - It looks like it ends up giving you 0. Do i need to use x^2?

Comment: You should get $b = - k/(2a))$ Remember - product rule with derivatives.

Comment: I get b = -kx/2a

Comment: You cannot get the constant to be a function of $x$.

Comment: it is unavoidable. The x's on left side cancel with each other and you end up with terms without extra x. How do you keep yours?

Comment: $f'' - a^2 f = (-2 a b e^{-ax} + a^2 b x e^{-ax}) - a^2 b x e^{-ax} = k e^{-ax}$, thus $b = -k/(2a)$.

Comment: I thought the right hand side was = kxe^-ax

Comment: You substitute $f_p = b x e^{-ax}$ into the LHS and equate that to the RHS of the De. I show the result above.

Comment: So finally, you get y  = C1e(ax) + C2e(-ax) -k/2a*x*e(-ax)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Another pirate in our midst! ;-) +1

Comment: I can see! Well, you did battle, and both of you won in the end!